# how to run .py script with user input as parameters

Tags: python, html, django, web

I have a .py file, say 'car.py'. It takes 3 inputs (color, make, year). It takes the user input and reads a file, then it returns all matching instances of the color, make, and year given in the input. This script runs fine.

Now, I would like to create a web page that works like a search page. It asks for 3 inputs, searches the file (locally) and returns the results.

I am using Django for the first time and I am having difficulty figuring out how to call the car.py file and have it run on the background before it returns the result.

I have an html interface made but I know I cant ref a python script in it. Is there anything similar in Django? Where I can reference a script and when a button is pressed, it'd run that script given the user input?

I don't expect a full coded response, I just want a clarification or reference to an answer. I haven't been able to find anything similar online.

Comment: Are you trying to have this search happen without reloading/changing the current page? In that case, using Javascript or another asynchronous option that runs the search might be right. If you don't mind loading a new page, you could create a form that submits to an route/endpoint that runs the search and displays the results.

Comment: What about _PHP_ function [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.exec.php)? Can you handle the form post in _PHP_ and from it execute a shell command that runs the script with the user inputs as arguments?

Comment: @Andrew Zick, the page can be reloaded. How exactly would a form submit to a route/endpoint? Could you expand on that a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna move my response of how to submit a form in Django to here instead of a comment, since it's more of an answer now.

When you submit a form, typically a POST request is sent to a website with the form's values in it. So when I say the form would submit to a route, I mean that a POST request would be sent to a particular view in your Django website, a view which could basically be your car.py file with a few changes. Here's [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-form-class) of a form, which would take in your three desired inputs, and here's [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view) of a view that could basically be your "car.py", and [a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template).

A rough example of your view:

```
def search_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data with your code from "car.py"
            # render your results page
            return render(request, 'results.html')
    # if a GET (or anything else) just render the same search page again
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})
```

SearchForm() can be whatever values you want from the user.